# How does for loop work when indexing csv files?

Tags: pandas, csv, for-loop

I'm using a large csv file with a lot of information. It was created based on a biopandas file by extracting l the rows that start with "ATOM". I managed to extract only the columns I need, but it only seems to read the letters in the first row. I need it to read the values in the next rows by column.

This is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

p1 = pd.read_csv ('1xao.csv',index_col='atom_name',usecols=['atom_name','x_coord','y_coord','z_coord'])
print('info in csv',p1)

for row in p1:
    for column in row:
        a=row[1]
        x=row[2]
        y=row[3]
        z=row[4]

        print('after the for loop',a,x,y,z)
```

And the output is

```
info in csv            x_coord  y_coord  z_coord
|atom_name |         |         |        |
|N         | -20.557 |  15.418 |  15.416|
|CA        | -21.279 |  14.111 |  15.335|
|C         | -20.626 |  13.120 |  14.374|
|O         | -20.124 |  13.507 |  13.318|
|CB        | -22.723 |  14.347 |  14.907|
|...       |     ... |     ... |     ...|
|CA        | -12.469 |  -1.643 |  -2.404|
|C         | -12.890 |  -2.022 |  -0.985|
|O         | -14.089 |  -2.315 |  -0.787|
|CB        | -11.354 |  -2.564 |  -2.882|
|OXT       | -12.019 |  -2.015 |  -0.089|

[1782 rows x 3 columns]
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
after the for loop _ c o o
>>>
```

So when it goes into the for loop that's when the problem starts. I want a line that outputs: N,-20.557,15.418,15.416, and so on for all my atom names

I'm pretty sure I'm not using it right, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

#### `for x in df`:

When you iterate over a DataFrame like this **you iterate over the column labels, NOT the DataFrame**. This because `__iter__` uses the `info_axis`, which is the columns for a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=1, columns=['X_1234', 'Y_ABC', 'Z_abc'], 
                  index=['foo', 'bar'])

df.__iter__?
#Signature: df.__iter__()
#Docstring: Iterate over info axis.

df._info_axis
#Index(['X_1234', 'Y_ABC', 'Z_abc'], dtype='object')
```

---

So basically your loop is very mangled; you're referring to variables as rows and columns. What you refer to as a `row` is really the column label and then when you iterate over that (being a string) you get a character.

Because your labels are `'x_coord'`, `'y_cood'`, `'z_coord'` the 1st character in all of them is `'_'`, the 2nd, 3rd and 4th are 'c', 'o', '0', respectively. A more appropriate naming scheme for your loop is the following:

```
for col_lab in df:
    for char in col_lab:  # This does nothing as you never use char and only
        char1=col_lab[1]  # reference label. Essentially you just repeat this
        char2=col_lab[2]  # print N times, where N is the number of characters
        char3=col_lab[3]  # in each label. 
        char4=col_lab[4]
        
        print('after the for loop', char1, char2, char3, char4)

#after the for loop _ 1 2 3   |
#after the for loop _ 1 2 3   |
#after the for loop _ 1 2 3   | Repeated 6 times, i.e len('X_1234')
#after the for loop _ 1 2 3   |
#after the for loop _ 1 2 3   |
#after the for loop _ 1 2 3   |
#after the for loop _ A B C   \
#after the for loop _ A B C   \
#after the for loop _ A B C   \ Repeated 5 times, i.e len('Y_ABC')
#after the for loop _ A B C   \
#after the for loop _ A B C   \
#after the for loop _ a b c
#after the for loop _ a b c
#after the for loop _ a b c
#after the for loop _ a b c
#after the for loop _ a b c
```

---

If you *need* to iterate over the rows of a DataFrame you can use `iterrows` or `itertuples`. `iterrows` turns each row into a Series, where the original DataFrame column labels are now the row-labels for that Series. The row label becomes the Series name.

```
for r_label, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row, '\n')

#X_1234    1
#Y_ABC     1
#Z_abc     1
#Name: foo, dtype: int64
#
#X_1234    1
#Y_ABC     1
#Z_abc     1
#Name: bar, dtype: int64
```

Comment: With the "char" loop I got the same output as my initial loop. _ c o o

With the iterative process I got a better result, but I don't really know how to turn it into a line

Answer (score 0):

So the objecive of making the for loop was to get a line with all my values, but it turns out, I don't even need it. To solve that, all I did was turn the data frame into a matrix, flattened it and turned it back into a data frame. Here's the code if anyone needs it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

p1 = pd.read_csv ('1xao.csv',usecols=['atom_name','x_coord','y_coord','z_coord'])

n=p1.to_numpy()
f=n.flatten()

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(f)
df.to_csv('1xaolineal.csv')
```