# Why is my for loop trying to start on the header row instead of the first row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe with filepaths/names in it. I'm trying to loop through and do data transformation on each filename in the dataframe. Dataframe is:

```
Filename
filepath/filename1.xlsx
filepath/filename2.xlsx
filepath/filename3.xlsx
```

When I start my for loop:

```
for z in dfFileList[1:]:
    df = pd.read_excel(z)
```

I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Filename'

Since it seems to be reading the header as a row, I thought [1:] would skip the header and start on the first row with an actual filepath, but it doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108631/how-does-for-loop-work-when-indexing-csv-files/66108991#66108991

For `z in df` iterates over the column labels, **not** the values of the DataFrame. You would want `for z in dfFileList['Filename']:`

Comment: Thank you so much.